# How to create Floor Plan using HTML maps

Tags: php, javascript, imagemap

I went through this website, i found it really helpful in understanding/viewing floor map :

http://www.mouseonhouse.com/property/45/8708/

I wanted to make something like this. How can i manage the floor plan dynamically from backend? If you look into the link that i pasted above, you will find an image for floor plan on right side and you will notice that you can see the detail image of any part in floor plan by clicking into it. I know they use the HTML maps and areas to implement this concept.

Is their any way/tool so that i can manage to make floor plan similarly from backend, like i upload an image of floor plan and then point out different areas and finally it creates something like HTML code for maps. and i show it on front-end.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you work with image maps, I'd advice you to look at [ImageMapster JQuery plugin](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/), it can realy help with many image-map manipulation tasks.

Comment: I looked in it and it seems to be very useful...I am thinking to integrate it, just waiting for some other tool(if someone else suggest). Otherwise i will tick mark you answer. Thanks for your advice @Dane Soul

Comment: I used ImageMapster myself and like how it works. Moreover, the developer of that plugin is here on StackOverflow, and he helps, if you meet some specific tasks (I had problem with both-way synchronisation of 2 image maps) you can't solve yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap to create image maps by tracing over images. I've used it on a real estate site to great effect. That does involve a third-party though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [my online image map creator](http://www.kolchose.org/simon/ajaximagemapcreator/)!

It's an old test from me, but still works.